# window.location = "STAY ON CURRENT SITE"

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want that all visitors that are not from EN get redirected, but visitors from EN should stay on the site. Is there a command for that?

```
    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>


<script language="JavaScript">

var country= geoip_country_code();

if(country  == "EN")      
{
<!--
window.location = "STAY ON SITE"
//-->
}

else   
{
<!--
window.location = "https://www.sample.com/"
//-->
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't set `window.location`, and it will stay on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do anything if `country == "EN"`.

```
if (country !== "EN")
    window.location = "https://www.sample.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably get the browser locale to determine the information. Quick google search provided this script:

```
if ( navigator ) {
if ( navigator.language ) {
    return navigator.language;
}
else if ( navigator.browserLanguage ) {
    return navigator.browserLanguage;
}
else if ( navigator.systemLanguage ) {
    return navigator.systemLanguage;
}
else if ( navigator.userLanguage ) {
    return navigator.userLanguage;
}
```

}

Apart from that, I would implement this behavior on the server side, IMHO. And of course, you don't have to set window location, if the locale is the desired one.